# How to get the dynamic content using selenium via python after page load

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

I'm trying to grab content that loads dynamically using selenium via python3 after page load. I tried every solution I could find here but none of them works.

Specifically what I need is the value of href, but for now just being able to retrieve the entire page source with all the content after page-load would work as well.

Example of href value I need:

```
<a class="class1 class2" href="/path1/path2/path3/lsdkfughjfsldkfghsdlf">
```

I tried the following:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".class1.class2")))
```

Which errors with this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Image-image")))
    File "C:\Users\Mike\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

If I remove that and try this:

```
page_source = driver.page_source
driver.close()
with open(r"output.txt", "w") as f:        
   f.write(page_source)
```

Then I just get the loaded HTML page.

Additional configurations I am using that may be helpful in finding a solution:

```
s = Service("chromedriver.exe")
options = Options()
options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ''Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=s)
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you use the `WebDriverWait(driver, 20)` then it's highly likely that one would get `TimeoutException`, Can you try with `print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.Image-image").get_attribute('href'))` and let us know what's the exact error ?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a.Image-image"}

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML:

```
<a class="class1 class2" href="/path1/path2/path3/lsdkfughjfsldkfghsdlf">
```

Your [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) technically seems perfecto:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".class1.class2")))
```

However, simply using the values of the *class* attribute may not identify the element uniquely within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). In such cases you may require to construct a more canonical locator by adding the *`<tag_name>`* as well as the ***partial*** static value of the *`href`* attribute as follows:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.class1.class2[href]"))).get_attribute("href"))
```

more canonically

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.class1.class2[href*='path']"))).get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: fullxpath
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/article/a

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! 

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a.class1.class2[href*='path']"}

Some more information:

fullxpath: /html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/article/a

If I get rid of this: [href*='path']

Then I get this: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4dba0c9fa1f94c8111e48e14a4ea7d79", element="4493c9cd-55f3-4df1-a7b2-d061d08527c4")>

Does that extra info help?

Comment: @Awsmike This answer is based on the HTML you have provided `<a class="class1 class2" href="/path1/path2/path3/lsdkfughjfsldkfghsdlf">` Incase the actual HTML differs from the example HTML you would need to change the locators as well.

Comment: Understood and yes they've been changed. I have confirmed inspecting the element via Chrome that they match. do I need to update [href*='path'] with the actual path of one or leave that part as is?

Comment: @Awsmike Ofcoarse _`Asset--anchor`_ is a valied value for _class_ attribute. Yes, you need to replace **`path`** within `[href*='path']` with a static partial value.

Comment: Received this: TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable  ; I tried using a partial value "/path1/" for example and also the full path "/path1/path2/path3/lsdkfughjfsldkfghsdlf" which both resulted in that TypeError. I feel I am close to the solution.

Comment: @Awsmike Drop the `/` characters from both the ends, simply pass a valid partial text e.g. _`path`_

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Same: TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable

Comment: Possibly the locator strategy doesn't identifies the desired element uniquely and it grabs a wrong element which doesn't have the partial text _`path`_ in it's `href` attribute.

Comment: would you be open to do a screenshare at a time that is convenient with you?

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Answer (score 0):

to address the below issue:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a.Image-image"}
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML-DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//a[@class='Image-image']
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If this is unique `//a[@class='Image-image']` then you need to check for the below conditions as well.

1. Check if it's in any `iframe/frame/frameset`.

   **Solution:** switch to iframe/frame/frameset first and then interact with this web element.
2. Check if it's in any `shadow-root`.

   **Solution:** Use `driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector` to have returned a web element and then operates accordingly.
3. Make sure that the element is rendered properly before interacting with it. Put some `hardcoded delay` or `Explicit wait` and try again.

   **Solution:** `time.sleep(5)` or

   `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='Image-image']"))).get_attribute("href")`
4. If you have redirected to a `new tab/ or new windows` and you have not **switched** to that particular `new tab/new window`, otherwise you will likely get `NoSuchElement` exception.

   **Solution:** switch to the relevant window/tab first.
5. If you have switched to an iframe and the new desired element is not in the same iframe context then first `switch to default content` and then interact with it.

   **Solution:** switch to default content and then switch to respective iframe.

Comment: Not sure if this is unique or not: //*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[9]/div/article/a

Comment: I have mentioned the steps to check if it's unique or not. Please read `Steps to check:` section above

Comment: Yes - I wasn't sure if the slashes after the first " ] " meant it was or wasn't unique, but I checked all 5 conditions and still get the same error (with the exception of using WebDriverWait) which TimesOut

Comment: Not sure if I got you correctly or not. When you looked for `//a[@class='Image-image']` XPath how many entry you see in HTMLDOM?

Comment: ('Image-image' was just an example I used to simplify my question, but this is the Xpath //*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[9]/div/article/a   this last "a" element is the one I need

Comment: this is a horrible xpath `//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[9]/div/article/a`. Also if `'Image-image` was just for an example, why it is present in error stack trace `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Image-image")))
    File "C:\Users\Mike\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)` ?

Comment: It was present initially because I simply copied and pasted it to test it out without changing the values. I replaced the values later when I realized what happened, but the horrible xpath is the xpath for the actual dynamic content.

Comment: Just following up... would you happen to know the correct code with the horrible xpath?